# C++ Passing user input to a variable to a parameter for a function in

Tags: c++, parameters

I'm a huge noob when it comes to programming, but i've been watching some tutorials on youtube and I decided to try to mix some of the concepts taught in different videos. What I want to do is have a function that has 3 parameters that calculates the return on a stock market investment. In my main I want to get the 3 parameters for the function from the user and store each one in a variable and use those variables for the parameters when I call my function. I am currently getting an error, but before I type the whole thing out i'll just show you guys my code and maybe you can spot the problem.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cmath>

  using namespace std;

float stockMarketCalculator(float p, float r, int t){
float a;

for(int day = 1; day <=t; day++){
    a = p * pow(1+r, day);
        cout << a << endl;
}

}

int main()
{
float p;
float r;
int t;


cout << "Please enter the principle" << endl;
cin >> p >> endl;

cout << "Please enter the rate" << endl;
cin >> r >> endl;

cout << "Please enter the time in days" << endl;
cin >> t >> endl;
cout << stockMarketCalculator(p, r, t);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: >> endl does not work with cin, you need to remove them. also stockMarketCalculator need to return a value

Comment: Please expand upon "I am currently getting an error". Compile-time error? Run-time error? What is the output of the error?

Answer (score 1):

I read your prototype

```
float stockMarketCalculator(float p, float r, int t)
```

And assumed the function's return was important.
Indeed, from your main() function, you write:

```
cout << stockMarketCalculator(p, r, t);
```

Which, in your original code, will try to write some indeterminate value.

If you don't care about the return value, you should use:

```
void stockMarketCalculator(float p, float r, int t)
```

And don't try to `cout` the value from `main()` - just call it directly (see unziberla's answer).

On the other hand, if you do care about the return value, then add the `return` as in my original answer, below. It is a cleaner interface to do that if you only care about the final value.

**Original Answer:** (for posterity)

You need to add

```
return a;
```

To your `stockMarketCalculator`.

Often, this would be reported as a warning by your compiler, but may not be depending on your settings.

Comment: I think since he's outputting value every loop of iteration he doesn't need "cout << stockMarketCalculator(p, r, t);" at all, so he doesn't need to return a;

Answer (score 1):

first error: your stockMarketCalculator function should return value!

```
return a;
```

Second error (3 times): cin is not needed in endl. Just remove it.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Your code corrected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void stockMarketCalculator(float p, float r, int t)
{
    float a;

    for(int day = 1; day <= t; day++)
    {
        a = p * pow(1+r, day);
        cout << a << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    float p;
    float r;
    int t;

    cout << "Please enter the principle" << endl;
    cin >> p;

    cout << "Please enter the rate" << endl;
    cin >> r;

    cout << "Please enter the time in days" << endl;
    cin >> t;

    stockMarketCalculator(p, r, t);

    return 0;
}
```

**Corrections**

`cin` stream does not need `endl`

you don't need your `stockMarketCalculator` to return a value to be printed, because it is already printing the values you want, so I declared it `void` and simply called it in `main` function.

Comment: >.< can't believe it was this easy. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Also, you should probably learn how to read compiler errors. This would simplify your life.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, your `stockMarketCalculator` function says it will return a float, but has no return statement.

`return a;` goes after the for loop, before the closing curly brace of the `stockMarketCalculator` function.